# Merging dataframes from tables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a few tables that count the frequency of eye color across three dataframes. I thought I could translate those tables in dataframes, then merge them as a new dataframe. I believe is the error is coming from the fact that I transformed the tables into dataframes and merge seems to add on the rows of it. But I need:

```
Color  Tb1  Tb2   Tb3
Bl     5    0     3
Blk    6    7     0
```

Small condition is that not each dataframe has Black or Blue eye colors in it. So I need to account for that, then change the NA's to 0's.

I have tried:

```
chart<-merge(tb1,tb2,tb3)
chart
 Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

AND

```
chart<-merge(tb1,tb2,tb3,all=T)
chart
 Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

Example code:

```
one<-c('Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue')
two<-c('Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Black')
three<-c('Blue','Blue','Blue')
tb1<-table(one)
tb2<-table(two)
tb3<-table(three)
tb1<-as.data.frame(tb1)
tb2<-as.data.frame(tb2)
tb3<-as.data.frame(tb3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert all tables directly into one tibble using `bind_rows` from the package `dplyr`:

```
# creating the setup given in the question
one<-c('Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue')
two<-c('Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Black','Black')
three<-c('Blue','Blue','Blue')
tb1<-table(one)
tb2<-table(two)
tb3<-table(three)

# note that there is no need for individual dataframes

# bind the rows of the given tables into a tibble
result <- dplyr::bind_rows(tb1, tb2, tb3)

# replace NAs with 0 values
result[is.na(result)] <- 0

# check the resulting tibble
result
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Black  Blue
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     6     5
# 2     7     0
# 3     0     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it your way, I will do something as follows (column names are needed to be corrected):

```
newframe <- merge(tb1, tb2, by.x ="one", by.y ="two", all = TRUE)
merge(newframe, tb3, by.x ="one", by.y ="three", all = TRUE)
```

However, for nicer ways, check `dplyr()` joins.